# Bash script in Cron not running Python script on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Server

Tags: bash, python, cron

I have an Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Server which I run few Python scripts, I created a `cronjob` to run a Bash script to check and see if my Python script is running.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/python2.7


SERVICE="start_server.py"
if ps -ef | grep "$SERVICE" | grep -v grep >/dev/null
then
    echo "start_server.py is running" >> /home/ubuntu/mislaka/script_log.log
else
        python2.7 /home/ubuntu/mislaka/start_server.py &
    echo "start_server.py stopped" >> /home/ubuntu/mislaka/script_log.log
fi
```

This is the `cronjob` configuration:

```
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/mislaka/check_process.sh
```

When checking the `log` file I can see it is adding the `echo` commands to the file but it does not start the Python script. If I run my script outside of the `cronjob` it is working as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences between bash and sh shells.
If you are using bash you shoud use:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was my issue.
Instead of writing my command under the else statement in one line, I wrote it in two:

```
echo "start_server.py stopped" >> /home/ubuntu/mislaka/script_log.log && python2.7 start_server.py &
```

This fixed my issue.

Comment: That's unlikely, the only thing changed is the order in which the line is executed, I suspect you are missing the path to `start_server.py`